# Map Jolt Transformation

Tags: jolt

I am trying to transform the following input:

```json
{
    "test_types": {
        "3": "Type3",
        "21": "type21",
        "16": "Type16",
        "15": "type15"
    },
    "name": "BlackSquid",
    "obj_name": "malware",
    "value": "2341743",
    "type": "16"
}
```

Into this output:

```json
{
    "test_types": {
        "3": "Type3",
        "21": "type21",
        "16": "Type16",
        "15": "type15"
    },
    "name": "BlackSquid",
    "obj_name": "malware",
    "value": "2341743",
    "type": "16",
    "type_name": "Type16"
}
```

I have tried to use a "modify-overwrite-beta" spec by hardcoding the key value which gives me the result I need:

```json
[
  {
    "operation": "modify-overwrite-beta",
    "spec": {
      "type_name": "@(1,test_types.16)"
    }
  }
]
```

but I would like to use the "type" value dynamically. The following throws an exception but maybe something like this:

```json
[
  {
    "operation": "modify-overwrite-beta",
    "spec": {
      "type_name": "@(1,test_types.@(1,type))"
    }
    }
]
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No need to use **modify-overwrite-beta** spec, but condition based **shift** spec for the key **type** would suffice such as

```json
[{
  "operation": "shift",
  "spec": {
    "*": "&",
    "type": {
      "*": {
        "@(2,type)": "type",
        "@(2,test_types.&)": "type_name"
      }
    }
  }
}]
```